# How to use 'user.username' in the settings.py

Tags: django

I'm having trouble with my URL forwarding after successful login.

The django default for 'LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL' is '/accounts/profile/'. In my case it should forward to '/user/{{ user.username }}/'

I went to overwrite it in my settings file but have encountered a syntax issue. Here's the code:

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "/user/%s/" % user.username
```

When I use the following line in my login form, it works, but only if the page is reloaded first. Kinda strange.

```
<input type="hidden" name="user" value="/user/{{ user.username }}/" />
```

So what changes must I make to my settings.py to load the username on redirect?

Thanks.

Comment: if you can only get the current user from the request context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to create a custom login instead and use the views described in [django user authentication](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/).

Of course overriding the view where /accounts/profile/ points to and manually setting the redirect url there is an option, but its not a very elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

Of course there's a syntax issue, you're referencing a variable, `user`, in settings.py that doesn't exist there. It might help you to go through a Python tutorial to understand Python's scoping rules.

In any case, settings.py is for static global settings. Usernames obviously vary per user, so you can't put a dynamic setting there.